# How to set composite primary key if one of the propery is inherited?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm exprimenting with ef code first approach.
I have a base class:

```
    [Serializable]
    [Table("PayerEntity")]
    public abstract class PayerEntity
    {
      [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int PayerEntityId { get; set; }
    }
```

Another one is descendand from it:

```
    [Serializable]
    [Table("Group")]
    public class Group : PayerEntity
    {
      public int GroupId { get; set; }

      [MaxLength(50,ErrorMessage = "Max 50")]
      public string SomeGroupProp { get; set; }
    }
```

In the context class I override the OnModelCreating method:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasKey(p => new { p.PayerEntityId, p.GroupId });
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

But only the "PayerEntityId" column will be primary key.
I really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Péter

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to create a 1-to-1 relationship between tables with different key settings.  This isn't possible to constrain (at least in SQL) so it seems EF is doing it's best to define the 1-to-1 relationship, by having both tables use the same key.

If you wanted a 1-to-many relationship between `PayerEntity` and `Group` you should create classes that don't inherit from each other.

```
[Table("PayerEntity")]
public  class PayerEntity
{
  public PayerEntity()
  {
        this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
  }

  [Key]
  public int PayerEntityId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

[Table("Group")]
public class Group
{
  public int PayerEntityId { get; set; }
  public int GroupId { get; set; }
  public virtual PayerEntity PayerEntity { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Group>().HasKey(p => new { p.PayerEntityId, p.GroupId });
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
        .HasRequired(a => a.PayerEntity)
        .WithMany(b => b.Groups)
}
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the answer.
I imagine the structure like this:
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130128/DBDiagram_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png
The only problem with your answer is that you don't use the object inheritance, but the modell logic suggest that the Group should derived from the PayerEntity not contain.

Comment: You could remove `PayerEntityId` and `GroupId` from Group and have Group derive from `PayerEntity`. In this setup you wouldn't be able to keep the composite key, `PayerEntityId` would be the primary key for Group.

Comment: Thanks, I came to this solution. The original plan was not feasible.
I can't set your comments as the solution.